# Bundler can't install signet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundler, rbenv

I've just removed `rbenv` as i wanted to install a newer Ruby version (2.6) than the ones available for `rbenv`, then installed Ruby 2.6, that went fine, now while trying to reinstall all the gems for my app I ran into the following problem:

```
$ bundle install
Installing signet 0.14.0
Gem::InstallError: signet requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0.
An error occurred while installing signet (0.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install signet -v '0.14.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  google_drive was resolved to 2.1.12, which depends on
    google-api-client was resolved to 0.21.2, which depends on
      googleauth was resolved to 0.6.7, which depends on
        signet
```

But ruby has clearly been upgraded:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

and if I try to install signet manually it works fine:

```
gem install signet -v '0.14.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Successfully installed signet-0.14.0
Parsing documentation for signet-0.14.0
Done installing documentation for signet after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But then if i run `bundle install` again I still get the same problem. I've also tried `bundle install --path vendor/cache` and `bundle install --system` to no avail.

Note that the gems seem to install in the right place:

```
gem which signet
/var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/signet-0.14.0/lib/signet.rb
```

if I compare it to another one installed by bundler:

```
gem which multi_json
/var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/multi_json-1.14.1/lib/multi_json.rb
```

This is on `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS` and `bundler 1.16.3`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally figured it out, installing a newer version of bundler (but < 2.0 as Rails 4.2 requires it) did the trick, although i also had to uninstall the ruby 2.2-dev package and install the 2.6-dev package to be able to compile native gems like `nokogiri`, then running the whole thing specifying the bundler version.

For those interested, these were the commands:

```
apt-get remove ruby-dev
apt install ruby2.6-dev
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
bundle _1.17.3_ install
```